# $c^1$-differentiability in locally convex spaces

Tags: locally-convex-spaces

Let $f: E \to F$ be a $\mathcal C^1$-map between locally convex spaces. Is the following correct 
$$
\mathrm{d}f(x)(h) = \langle f'(x),h\rangle\:\:?
$$

Comment: You might want to explain your notation. What is $f'(x)$ for you?

Comment: In case you are asking whether the Gateaux derivative at $x$ of $f$ in direction $h$ is equal to the Frechet differential of $f$ at $x$ applied to $h$; yes, that is true.

Comment: Thanks, Severin. I meant that. Is it true for any topology on the dual space?

Comment: What do you mean by the dual space?

Comment: the differential df( x) belongs to the dual space E', and <,> is the duality between E' and E. I know this is true for the Banach case but I was as not sure about locally convex space because there different topologies on E'.

Comment: You can google On Differentials in Locally Convex Spaces, then it should be one of the first theorems.

Comment: I couldn't find it, I saw just for Banach spaces

Comment: What do you mean? On Differentials in Locally Convex Spaces is the name of the paper by Falb and Jacobs. Just google it.

Comment: I just read that paper but there is nothing about that.

Comment: I am confused, doesn't Theorem 1 exactly say what you want?

Comment: Theorem 1 says that the strong differentibility implies weak differentiability but it doesn't mention anything about duality

Comment: It says $$ d_w f(x,h) = df(x,h) $$ which is what you want. The LHS is the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ in direction $h$ and the RHS is the derivative of $f$ at $x$ applied to $h$.